# Run 2 JavaScript scripts at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to run a huge jQuery banner and photo gallery at same time using external JS, but I don't know what code to use to make both run together in one HTML, please help.

Here the code:

Photo gallery :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Banner:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script2.js"></script>
```

Both codes are inside `<head>`.

Let me know if you need anything to make it clear.

Comment: The code that you showed is simply including the libraries in your page but it isn't running anything yet. You need to show the relevant code that actually starts the gallery and the banner.

Comment: _Mother of God_, why are you loading `prototype`, `scriptaculous`, AND `jQuery` on the same page?

Comment: By same time, do u mean simultaneously? As this wont happen as js engine will parse the code from top to bottom.

Answer (score 2):

jquery and prototype sometimes conflict. there seems to be a possibility to avoid that (i haven't tested it so far). try changing your banner-code to this - does that help?

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    var $j = jQuery;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script2.js"></script>
```

anyway, i would suggest using a different, probably jquery powered lightbox-script like [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) so you don't need that overhead of jquery, prototype and scriptaculous

Comment: You should probably mention, that this will only work if code in `js/script2.js`  uses `jQuery` and not `$` to access the jQuery functionality.